# Sonar Java: check the quality of the test classes source code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube, rules

Is it possible to check in Sonar the quality of the *Test.java source code, e.g. Methods maximum size 100 lines?

The problem is, that the Java Junit tests are growing with the productive code, also the complexity.

We have unit test classes with more than 1000 lines and 2 methods.

We want to check in Sonar some rules for these *Test.java classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Sonar 3.1, it includes a plugin that has specific PMD rules to be executed against the unit tests ([a JIRA was created for that](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-1076)). You can see them in the `Configuration > Quality Profiles > Coding Rules`.

However, it seems that you want to run a full analysis on the *test* source code, like you do on the *production* source code, and get additional metrics (for ex. a `% rules compliance` and also a `% rules compliance for unit tests`). I don't think that Sonar provides such feature natively. What you can do is to run 2 Sonar analysis:

1. Your first analysis is the current one;
2. The second analysis will consider the `src/test/java` as the "*production*" source code. Thus, this second analysis will give you the quality of your code. For this analysis, you can specify a specific Maven profile (or an alternative `pom.xml`) that will change the project information (for ex. it will indicate that `src/test/java` is the default `sourceDirectory`).

Comment: thx, that's what i need, not a full analysis but some rules :)

Comment: In Sonar >3.4 you can copy your own rules and improve the "PMD Unit Tests" plugin

Answer (score 7):

I also noticed that SonarQube will by default ignore the test resources for quality analysis. Using schnatterers answer, i found a simple way to create a separate project only including the test classes as sources in SonarQube, therefore triggering the quality anlysis on them. In the POM of the project i want to analyze i add a profile, which changes the sonar properties accordingly:

```
    <profiles>
            <profile>
                    <id>analyze-test-classes</id>
                    <properties>
                            <sonar.sources>src/test/java</sonar.sources>
                            <sonar.tests></sonar.tests>
                            <sonar.projectName>${project.name}-tests</sonar.projectName>
                            <sonar.projectKey>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}-tests</sonar.projectKey>
                    </properties>
            </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Running Maven with

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Panalyze-test-classes
```

will then activate this profile and create an additional project in SonarQube with the suffix -tests, which only contains the analysis of the test classes.

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With SonarQube 4.5.2 (don't know when they changed the behavior) it seems to me that unit tests are no longer excluded from the analysis. When running `sonar-runner` with `sonar.sources=src` sonar also creates issues for `src/test/java`.

One approach to use a specific quality ruleset for test code would be to run two analyses: one for the main code and another one for the testing code.
This can be realized as follows:

sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.projectName=testSonar
sonar.projectKey=testsonar
sonar.sources=src/main/java
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
```

- Analyse main code: `sonar-runner`
- Analyse test code: `sonar-runner -Dsonar.projectKey=testsonar.test -Dsonar.sources=src/test/java -Dsonar.projectName="testSonar TEST"`

The different quality profiles must be changed via the server (Dashboard | Project Configuration |  Quality Profiles), because `-Dsonar.profile` [is deprecated](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters).

This should also work with analyses through maven or jenkins.

Comment: How do you run this in a Jenkins Job ?  should you run 2 jobs (one for the main analyse and one for the tests) ?

Comment: I'd recommend to use only one job with two analyses, because it's faster and easier to maintain. You could add another post build step (either sonar or a shell that executes the maven goal) an pass the testing parameters (`-D`) as stated above